# Composite Primary Key usage in REST Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I never saw this form helpful to me. I wish it will be now.

In my spring-boot, My database has two primary keys

> TransId  and PrsnRef

Now When I create Entity's for my database Table named PersonCore I am getting 2 classes

> PersonCore (As known this has all rest of data)

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the PERSON_CORE database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON_CORE")
@NamedQuery(name="PersonCore.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM PersonCore f")
public class PersonCore implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonCorePK id;

    @Column(name="PRSN_AGE")
    private BigDecimal prsnAge;

    @Column(name="PRSN_AMER_INDIAN_ALASKA_NTV")
    private String prsnAmerIndianAlaskaNtv;

    @Column(name="PRSN_DOB")
    private String prsnDob;
```

> PersonCorePK (This has two Id's transid and personref)

```
    /**
 * The primary key class for the PERSON_CORE database table.
 * 
 */
@Embeddable
public class PersonCorePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="TRANS_ID")
    private String transId;

    @Column(name="PRSN_REF")
    private String prsnRef;

    public FdshPersonCorePK() {
    }
    public String getTransId() {
        return this.transId;
    }
    public void setTransId(String transId) {
        this.transId = transId;
    }
    public String getPrsnRef() {
        return this.prsnRef;
    }
    public void setPrsnRef(String prsnRef) {
        this.prsnRef = prsnRef;
    }
```

I am trying to create a RESTFul service using spring-boot 
I created repository with @RepositoryRestResource(bla bla bla)

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "person", collectionResourceRel = "FdshPersonHDR")
public interface PersonCoreRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<PersonCore, PersonCorePK> {
    Collection<PersonCore > findAll();
    Collection<PersonCore > findAllByIdTransIdAndIdPrsnRef(@Param("transid")String transId, @Param("prsnRef") String prsnRef);
}
```

Spring boot is so awesome that it takes good care of me.
Lets see ...

When I try to fetch all records from database its all fine except the final link is something like this

> http://localhost:8080/person/com.----.Application.Methods.PersonCorePK@83e14116

This is driving me crazy. I know its reading what I want but not displaying me exactly what I need.  I want help figuring out how I can convert that "com.----.Application.Methods.PersonCorePK@83e14116" . It should actually display transid of that record.

And please let me know if there is anyway we can add those two composite keys to that o/p format because I am getting all data I want except those two which are kind of important for me. I am not sure I can use two @Id's in single Entity. But I will check into it.

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IGVb.png)

Comment: Do you mean "I'd like a sensible override of the toString() method in the PersonCorePK class"?

Comment: Thank's for quick response sir, Nothing about classes I am trying to figure out if there is a way to display that "com.----.Application.Methods.PersonCorePK@83e14116"  as transID

Comment: I have a generic solution in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763250/spring-data-rest-with-composite-primary-key/43832551#43832551[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763250/spring-data-rest-with-composite-primary-key/43832551#43832551)

Comment: Hope this will help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763250/spring-data-rest-with-composite-primary-key/43832551#43832551](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763250/spring-data-rest-with-composite-primary-key/43832551#43832551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is the output of a `toString()` call on a `PersonCorePK` object. If you want to change the way this object is represented as a String, you need to override the `toString()` method for the PersonCorePK class. Something like this:

EDIT: New toString() method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "/search/findAllByIdTransIdAndIdPrsnRef?transId="+transId+"&prsnRef="+prsnRef;
}
```

I tried that it **it worked for me**. Slow down and be sure you understand is going on. Also, note that I changed `(@Param("transid")` to `(@Param("transId")` with an uppercase `I`.

Also, I added a constructor for the PersonCorePK:

```
public PersonCorePK(String transId, String prsnRef) {
    this.transId = transId;
    this.prsnRef = prsnRef;
}
```

Finally, when I tested the application I made sure to put a `Content-Type` of `application/json` in the `POST` request so that the system understands the data it is receiving.

I used [Accessing JPA Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) as a guide.

Comment: I Override transid String. But when I try to redirect using that link I am getting this error.."org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com..Methods.PersonCorePK]"

Comment: Please work on your grammar. See edits in answser. The toString method goes in the PersonCorePK class, as described.

Comment: That's so awesome. You are my hero Nicholas... :) Sorry for my poor  grammar.

Comment: Well now i figured out how to accept answer Nichol. Sorry! But thank you. though.